# custom customer attribute value in the e-mail template

Tags: magento2, product, customer, custom-options, magento2.2

I have install `Clarion_CustomerAttribute` and I don't know how to recall **attribute value** in the **e-mail template**

I have tried Address Templates configuration and nothing.

I use Port theme.

Comment: i have try`d{{var $customer.getSomeVarHere()}} and {{depend var $customer.attributecode()}}
     {{var $customer.attributecode()}}
 {{/depend}}

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Did you get the answer??